# Pandas - given a sorted dataframe and a list of target values, how to retrieve rows next to these values in one go

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a sorted dataframe and a list of target values as below

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]: 
   value
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
In [58]: target_values=[1.5, 3.5, 5.5]
```

What I want is to get the first row which has a value >= the target value respectively. In the example above, the index of such rows are [1, 3, 5].

I can achieve the goal with following code

```
In [60]: [df[df.value >= t].iloc[0] for t in target_values]
```

However, it will scan the dataframe for len(target_values) times. Is there a Pandas function which can achieve the goal with just one scan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html).  You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) method, or [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

**`pandas`**

```
df.value.searchsorted(target_values)

array([1, 3, 5])
```

**`numpy`**

```
df.value.values.searchsorted(target_values)

array([1, 3, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#build a pair wise difference matrix
pairwise_diff = df.values[:,None]-target_values

#find the non-negative min diff for each value in target values.
np.ma.array(pairwise_diff,mask=(pairwise_diff<0)).argmin(0)
Out[178]: array([[1, 3, 5]], dtype=int64)
```